# Exception from container-launch on a mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I've setup a hadoop cluster with one master node and 3 datanodes. When I try to run a mapreduce job on the master node I get the following error:

```
18/05/23 19:22:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1527096061793_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1527096061793_0001_01_000002
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
```

I've managed to find the error in the data nodes log files as well but they don't say anything more than has been shown in the console. I'm really stuck for quite some time now and I'm not sure how to approach this one. Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Thanks

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<!-- core-site.xml -->
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://NameNode:9000/</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
<value>131072</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>NameNode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.bind-host</name>
<value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.bind-host</name>
<value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/yarn/local</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/yarn/log</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
<value>hdfs://NameNode:9000/var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<!-- hdfs-site.xml -->

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namesecondary</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.permissions</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.block.size</name>
<value>134217728</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
<value>0.0.0.0:10020</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
<value>0.0.0.0:19888</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir</name>
<value>/user/app</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
<value>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
<value>2000</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
<value>2000</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
<value>1600</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
<value>1600</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Hadoop version is 2.7.6

Comment: Can you check if all the required services are running, like hdfs, yarn

Comment: @KetanKeshri They were, checked with jps. The problem was in the mapred-site.xml configuration file. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. It was in the mapred-site.xml configuration file on these lines here:

```
<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
<value>1600</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
<value>1600</value>
</property>
```

Every value inside the  tag should have an "-Xmx" prefix and an "m" suffix.

The right way to configure these properties:

```
<property>
<name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
<value>-Xmx1600m</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
<value>-Xmx1600m</value>
</property>
```

Hope this helps someone as it took way too much of my time to figure it out.

Comment: I had the same problem. I couldn't figure it out from logs. Managed to solve it with your help.